# Why will geom_tile plot a subset of my data, but not more?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a map, but I can not figure out why the following will not work:

Here is a minimal example

```
testdf <- structure(list(x = c(48.97, 44.22, 44.99, 48.87, 43.82, 43.16, 38.96, 38.49, 44.98, 43.9), y = c(-119.7, -113.7, -109.3, -120.6,  -109.6, -121.2, -114.2, -118.9, -109.7, -114.1), z = c(0.001216,  0.001631, 0.001801, 0.002081, 0.002158, 0.002265, 0.002298, 0.002334, 0.002349, 0.00249)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This works for 1-8 rows:

```
ggplot(data = testdf[1,], aes(x,y,fill = z)) + geom_tile()
ggplot(data = testdf[1:8,], aes(x,y,fill = z)) + geom_tile()
```

But not for 9 rows:

```
ggplot(data = testdf[1:9,], aes(x,y,fill = z)) + geom_tile()
```

Ultimately, I am seeking a way to plot data on a non-regular grid. It is not essential that I use geom_tile, but any space-filling interpolation over the points will do.

#### The full dataset is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/raw/4635980/f657dcdfab7b951c7b8b921b3a109c7df1697eb8/test.csv)

`testdf` above was a small subset of the full dataset, a high-resolution raster of the US (>7500 rows)

```
require(RCurl) # requires libcurl; sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
tmp <- getURL("https://gist.github.com/raw/4635980/f657dcdfab7b951c7b8b921b3a109c7df1697eb8/test.csv")
testdf <- read.csv(textConnection(x))
```

#### What I have tried:

1. using geom_point works, but does not have the desired effect:

   ```
   ggplot(data = testdf, aes(x,y,color=z)) + geom_point()
   ```
2. if I convert *either* x or y to a vector 1:10, the plot works as expected:

   ```
   newdf <- transform(testdf, y =1:10)

   ggplot(data = newdf[1:9,], aes(x,y,fill = z)) + geom_tile()

   newdf <- transform(testdf, x =1:10)
   ggplot(data = newdf[1:9,], aes(x,y,fill = z)) + geom_tile()
   ```

---

```
sessionInfo()R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)


> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     

> other attached packages: [1] reshape2_1.2.2 maps_2.3-0    
> betymaps_1.0   ggmap_2.2      ggplot2_0.9.3 

> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] colorspace_1.2-0   
> dichromat_1.2-4     digest_0.6.1        grid_2.15.2        
> gtable_0.1.2        labeling_0.1         [7] MASS_7.3-23        
> munsell_0.4         plyr_1.8            png_0.1-4          
> proto_0.3-10        RColorBrewer_1.0-5  [13] RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.2
> rjson_0.2.12        scales_0.2.3        stringr_0.6.2      
> tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: Do you have some more information about the raster the data came from? i.e. the projection information

Comment: @SimonO101 they were generated on a 30x30km grid

Comment: Ok. You will need to do some resampling of your data. The points as they are not evenly spaced which is why you can't use `geom_raster` or `geom_tile`. See my answer for details and a solution that uses `geom_raster`.

Comment: does the below work on your system?

Comment: Abe - I applied the edit you correctly suggested but which was declined by reviewers before I had a chance to accept it! You are quite right, the script requires RCurl.

Comment: @SimonO101 yep - it works great. Thanks for your answer! But I am still stuck (and will comment below your answer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you can't use `geom_tile()` (or the more appropriate `geom_raster()` is because these two `geoms` rely on your tiles being evenly spaced, which they are not. You will need to  coerce your data to points, and resample these to an evenly spaced raster which you can then plot with `geom_raster()`. You will have to accept that you will need to resample your original data slightly in order to plot this as you wish.

You should also read up on `raster:::projection` and `rgdal:::spTransform` for more information on map projections.

```
require( RCurl )
require( raster )
require( sp )
require( ggplot2 )
tmp <- getURL("https://gist.github.com/geophtwombly/4635980/raw/f657dcdfab7b951c7b8b921b3a109c7df1697eb8/test.csv")
testdf <- read.csv(textConnection(tmp))
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame( data.frame( x = testdf$y , y = testdf$x ) , data = data.frame( z = testdf$z ) )

# Plotting the points reveals the unevenly spaced nature of the points
spplot(spdf)
```

[image]

```
# You can see the uneven nature of the data even better here via the moire pattern
plot(spdf)
```

[image]

```
# Make an evenly spaced raster, the same extent as original data
e <- extent( spdf )

# Determine ratio between x and y dimensions
ratio <- ( e@xmax - e@xmin ) / ( e@ymax - e@ymin )

# Create template raster to sample to
r <- raster( nrows = 56 , ncols = floor( 56 * ratio ) , ext = extent(spdf) )
rf <- rasterize( spdf , r , field = "z" , fun = mean )

# Attributes of our new raster (# cells quite close to original data)
rf
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 56, 135, 7560  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.424932, 0.4248191  (x, y)
extent      : -124.5008, -67.13498, 25.21298, 49.00285  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

# We can then plot this using `geom_tile()` or `geom_raster()`
rdf <- data.frame( rasterToPoints( rf ) )    
ggplot( NULL ) + geom_raster( data = rdf , aes( x , y , fill = layer ) )
```

[image]

```
# And as the OP asked for geom_tile, this would be...
ggplot( NULL ) + geom_tile( data = rdf , aes( x , y , fill = layer ) , colour = "white" )
```

[image]

Of course I should add that this data is quite meaningless. What you really must do is take the SpatialPointsDataFrame, assign the correct projection information to it, and then transform to latlong coordinates via spTransform and then rasterzie the transformed points. Really you need to have more information about your raster data. What you have here is a close approximation, but ultimately it is not a true reflection of the data.

Comment: I apologize in advance for being dense - I have some reading to do - but I don't understand the last part. Why is the data meaningless? Uncertainty associated with resampling is small, and the data set have lat and lon, so, e.g., I can see that the midwest has higher values than the west coast. What information does a project add other than what is needed for plotting? Is the projection used in the `rf` RasterLayer object wrong? There is more information about this data on [gis.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20052/3218). I am stuck trying to assign `gridded() <- TRUE`.

Comment: Ok, it's not quite meaningless, but effectively what we have done is overlaid a regular grid on top of what you see in the first pictures and assigned values to the regular grid based on where they are in the underlying picture. This isn't right. Transforming the data by reprojecting will cause some of your data points to shift more than others as a function of their latitude and longitude. If you don't care about accuracy and want a general overview then maybe you can use this, but I don't think it wouldn't be very defensible in a publication. Perhaps @PaulHiemstra could elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @SimonO101 yes you did - thanks for your help. Given the [assumptions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1757-1707.2011.01150.x) used to generate the map (it is not 'data' but model output) as well as the limited resolution of the color scale, I think it will be possible to justify some errors introduced during the mapping - my general rule of thumb is to ignore stuff that accounts for < 5% or so of the total uncertainty.

Answer (score 9):

This will not be answer to `geom_tile()` problem but another way to plot data.

As you have x and y coordinates of 30 km grid (I assume middle of that grid) then you can used `geom_point()` and plot data. You should select appropriate `shape=` value. Shape 15 will plot rectangles.

Another problem is x and y values - when plotting data they should be plotted as `x=y` and `y=x` to correspond to latitude and longitude.

`coord_equal()` will ensure that there is a correct aspect ratio (I found this solution with ratio as example on net).

```
ggplot(data = testdf, aes(y,x,colour=z)) + geom_point(shape=15)+
  coord_equal(ratio=1/cos(mean(testdf$x)*pi/180))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

answer:

data is plotted but is just very small.

---

[From here:](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/ggplot2/html/geom_tile.html)

```
"Tile plot as densely as possible, assuming that every tile is the same size.
```

Consider this plot

```
ggplot(data = testdf[1:2,], aes(x,y,fill = z)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

There are two tiles in the plot above. `geom_tile` is trying to make the plot as dense as possible considering that every tile is the same size. Here we can make two tiles this big without overlapping. making enough space for 4 tiles.

Have a go at the following plots and see what the resulting plots tell you:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1:3),y=(1:3))
#     df1
#  x   y
#1 1   1
#2 2   2
#3 3   3
ggplot(data = df1[1,], aes(x,y)) + geom_tile()   
ggplot(data = df1[1:2,], aes(x,y)) + geom_tile() 
ggplot(data = df1[1:3,], aes(x,y)) + geom_tile()
```

compare to this example:

```
 df2 <- data.frame(x=c(1:3),y=c(1,20,300))
 df2
 # x   y
#1 1   1
#2 2  20
#3 3 300

 ggplot(data = df2[1,], aes(x,y)) + geom_tile()
 ggplot(data = df2[1:2,], aes(x,y)) + geom_tile()
 ggplot(data = df2[1:3,], aes(x,y)) + geom_tile()
```

Note that for the first two plots are same for `df1` and `df2` but the third plot for `df2` is different. This is because the biggest we can make the tiles is between (`x[1],y[1])` and (`x[2],y[2])`. Any more and they would overlap which leaves lots of space between these two tiles and the last 3rd tile at `y=300`.

There is also a `width` parameter in `geom_tile` although I am not sure how sensible this is here. are you sure you dont fancy another option with such sparse data ?

(Your full data is still plotted: see `ggplot(data = testdf, aes(x,y)) + geom_tile(width=1000)`

Comment: Yes, but perhaps you could add a little explanation about how geom_tile is picking the size of the tiles based on how close together the points are...?

Comment: What other options do you suggest? Only the minimal example is sparse; the full data set is hare: https://www.betydb.org//miscanthusyield.csv

Comment: Exactly; it is a 7500 row raster of the US with a 30km grid spacing; I just reduced the problem while trying to find an answer myself, and for clarity of this question. I have deleted the previous comment and link and added the full data set example to my question. I will try `width` and get back to you. I am thinking that the issue might be the projection ...

Comment: I placed a bounty on this question seeking a solution to plotting the data that I have.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use geom_tile I think you will need to aggregate first:

```
# NOTE: tmp.csv downloaded from https://gist.github.com/geophtwombly/4635980/raw/f657dcdfab7b951c7b8b921b3a109c7df1697eb8/test.csv
testdf <- read.csv("~/Desktop/tmp.csv") 

# combine x,y coordinates by rounding
testdf$x2 <- round(testdf$x, digits=0)
testdf$y2 <- round(testdf$y, digits=0)

# aggregate on combined coordinates
library(plyr)
testdf <- ddply(testdf, c("x2", "y2"), summarize,
                z = mean(z))

# plot aggregated data using geom_tile
ggplot(data = testdf, aes(y2,x2,fill=z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  coord_equal(ratio=1/cos(mean(testdf$x2)*pi/180)) # copied from @Didzis Elferts answer--nice!
```

Once we have done all this we will probably conclude that geom_point() is better, as suggested by @Didzis Elferts.